# Sharing settings on accounts, cases, emails and attachments

Tags: attachment, emailmessage, sharing-sets

We have a requirement in which we need to make some accounts private. We do this by flagging the account with a deleted field. This flag is used in our sharing settings. We are using the exact same approach for cases. But we have no idea of how to hide emails and attachments. I cannot find neither emails nor attachments in the sharing settings.
Can anyone think of a workaround for this?
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the Case, you can see the Attachments and Emails on the record. You need to start by making all records Private (Organization Wide Defaults), then introduce sharing rules for exceptions to the default. You cannot grant "less" access than the default, only more.

Comment: The case is private, and access is granted to the case. But some people that cannot see the case, can see the email. That is what I am trying to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

What they are seeing is not the email itself, but the task associated with the e-mail. I will change the sharing settings on the Activity to controlled by parent and check if it works.

Comment: It did not, I additionally had to change the owner of the Task to a user higher up in the hierarchy since the owner can always see its content. The emails and attachments can still be seen by whoever sent them, since they are not owned.